# Label does not show on Gnuplot 2D heat map

Tags: gnuplot

I am a beginner of Gnuplot.
Now, I am trying to rewrite a Octave program for plotting on Gnuplot.
I have finished most of it, apart from putting mark(label) on the output graph.

My code is like this:

```
unset key;
set tic scale 0;

set terminal push; #remembers the current terminal including its settings while set term pop restores it.

set palette rgbformula 33,13,10;

set xrange [0:265];
set yrange [0:490];
set size ratio -1;

#------------------for label------------------------------
set label 1 at 60,290;
set label 1 "O" center tc rgb "white"; 
#---------------------------------------------------------

set terminal pngcairo;
set output 'test00001.png';

set view map;
plot 'testfile.dat' using 1:2:3 with image;

set terminal pop; #restore terminal
set output;
replot; #display on screen while output the .png file
```

The label doesn't show.
Could you please tell me why the label drawing failed and how can I draw a label on the graph?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It's hard to be sure because you didn't post your data file, but here is a guess: by default gnuplot places labels behind the data. To change that you have to specify the `front` property: `set label 1 "O" at  60,290 center front tc rgb "white"`

Comment: @user8153 The label shows now! Why don't you answer this question instead of comment? Thank you so much, my friend. Can I ask another question? Is the label vertical alignment as default? If it isn't, do you know how to set the label vertical alignment? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, gnuplot places labels behind the data. To make sure that labels appear in front of the data you have to specify the `front`  property:

```
set label 1 "O" at 60,290 center front tc rgb "white"
```

Both the horizontal and the vertical alignment are only estimates, and can vary with the font and also the chosen terminal type. If you require exact placement you might be better off placing a `circle` object:

```
set object 1 circle at 60,290 size 5 front fillstyle empty border rgb "white" linewidth 2
```